Define a div's style in the angular template at startup
I have this div
<div class="relative rounded overflow-clip border w-full" [style.aspect-ratio]="media.value.ratio">
            <img fill priority [ngSrc]="media.value.src || ftaLogo" [alt]="media.value.caption"
                 [style.object-fit]="media.value.fit" (click)="insertMedia()">
          </div>

at startup, I try to assign the aspect ratio based on a model but it does not apply, what's the problem?
the aspect ratio of my model is 16:9, even by examining in the browser, my style has never been applied.
But when I change the aspect ratio while the application is running (by clicking on a button) it works.

Sorry everyone. Thanks you for trying to help me.
I founded what was wrong. Data in my local database did not contain the ratio field, that's why ratio doesn't work first time my apologies. 
Will delete this Question

Could you try, aspectRatio instead of aspect-ratio
<div class="relative rounded overflow-clip border w-full" [style.aspectRatio]="media.value.ratio">
        <img fill priority [ngSrc]="media.value.src || ftaLogo" [alt]="media.value.caption"
             [style.objectFit]="media.value.fit" (click)="insertMedia()">
      </div>

You can also try [ngStyle]
<div class="relative rounded overflow-clip border w-full" [ngStyle]="{'aspect-ratio': media.value.ratio + ' !important' }">
        <img fill priority [ngSrc]="media.value.src || ftaLogo" [alt]="media.value.caption"
             [style.objectFit]="media.value.fit" (click)="insertMedia()">
      </div>

